# How are HTTP POST responses constructed? How can I recreate them with Python and urllib2 to simulate filling out a form?

Tags: python, post, urllib2, urllib

I've set up this simple website with just a form on it so I could practice filling out froms with Python: http://www.wix.com/yoshyaro/status-check.

Looking over [urllib2](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml) - The Missing Manual, I have my code configured as follows

```
url = 'http://www.wix.com/yoshyaro/status-check'
values = {'name':"my name",
          'email':"yoshyaro@yahoo.com",
          'subject':"Subject",
          'Message':"Hello"}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

As I understand this code to work, we are sending a POST request to the server with all of the form data packaged in the request. However, the method I'm using must be doing it wrong because nothing is happening. I'm not getting any confirmation emails.

So I filled out the form by hand, clicked submit, and watched Chrome's Network tab. I see one POST request with the following information.

```
Request URL:http://editor.wix.com/wixpress/sendEmail.jspx
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:886
Cookie:_wix_browser_sess=2086d943-1f2e-49e9-88d1-c09bbb514503; userType=REGISTERED; wixMobileEditor=0d42663f8a3da0153266b3162d390f57; s_session_id=0fb8f99e-41bf-4588-85bb-6428cf5ba16e; _wixRefX="www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cts=1330620782943&ved=0CIoBEBYwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2F&ei=Y6lPT-GjI-mIsgLH8om3Dg&usg=AFQjCNG4eaeAPBPCnLcG_xTc75FuiYPfOg"; _wixCampX=null-campaign; _wixExprX=null-expr; _wixLndX=10882255; _wixTSX=1330620778929; _wixUIDX=24872778|9ba62417-c8e2-4134-bb3f-2ff53b8e39f6; _wixCIDX=f2219c7f-a421-49b2-8995-056bda65232b; wixSession=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; wixClient=yoshyaro|yoshyaro@yahoo.com|NOT_VERIFIED_OPT_IN|0|1330622652098|1331918652098|9ba62417-c8e2-4134-bb3f-2ff53b8e39f6; wixLanguage=en-us; firstEditorSession=0; _wixAB2=622#2572#2012-03-09T08-21-15.000-0600|596#2356#2012-04-30T10-14-02.000-0500; __utma=41622436.41813915.1327611501.1330620785.1330625106.4; __utmb=41622436.2.10.1330625106; __utmc=41622436; __utmz=41622436.1330625106.4.3.utmcsr=static.wix.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/client/app.swf
Host:editor.wix.com
Origin:http://static.wix.com
Referer:http://static.wix.com/client/app.swf?cacheKiller=v%3D668&max-age=172800
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Form Dataview URL encoded
orgDocID:23287851
partner_id:WMGs4POB1ko-a
icon_file_name:9ba624_cc7e5becb5470aeefad64d8bf0d58476.wix_doc_ico
gu_id:ff72209a-5149-42e1-9ab4-c48690db9e5e
user_action:send_simple_email
experiment_id:empty
document_name:status-check
from_name:Name
user_name:yoshyaro
to:yoshyaro@yahoo.com
wixComputerID:JPgBWueD99+7DhhlYULLRJXbWSBbsxqoMbgepccE+qfEleS0yIMcGfyt2Ave2q5U6Vmw+vQ64Xs5q7p5Z1lMxw==
from:yoshyaro@yahoo.com
document_id:23287851
content:Name has sent you a message using your contact form at: <a href='http://www.wix.com/yoshyaro/status-check/My Website'>http://www.wix.com/yoshyaro/status-check/My Website</a>

Senders email: yoshyaro@yahoo.com


message

 Thank you for using WIX.COM
subject:subject
Response Headersview source
AppServer:app6.wixpress.com
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:125
Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 01 Mar 2012 18:20:39 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Via-Node:sputnik3
```

The first thing I noticed was that the Request URL is different than the one I have set. So I change my code to:

```
url = 'http://editor.wix.com/wixpress/sendEmail.jspx'
values = {'name':"my name",
          'email':"yoshyaro@yahoo.com",
          'subject':"Subject",
          'Message':"Hello"}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

But running this gives an HTTP 403 Error: Forbidden. Now going off the assumption that all I'm attempting to do is recreate a HTTP request in the appropriate manner, I started looking over the Network tab again to see what exactly such a request looks like. My plan at this point was to try recreating one by hand. However, this is where I'm stuck. I don't see any information relating to what's actually IN the POST request. I see what the output is, the "[name] has sent you a message" that gets displayed after the POST is made, but I can't find any of the actual form values anywhere.

So that's where I am. I'm unsure how to recreate a POST request because I'm somehat unsure what one even looks like..

Comment: in chrome network tab is there a 'persist' option so the data doesn't reset on page load?

Comment: related: [https POST using socket, httplib, urllib2](https://gist.github.com/1841962#file_http_post_httplib.py) -- ignore `ssl` part, all ingridients are there: start-line, headers, body.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package